Conditional Expectation of $X/Y$ given $X \leq 2Y$ for Independent Uniform Variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, each uniformly
distributed on $(0,1)$. Find the conditional expectation
$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{Y} \mid X \leq 2Y\right]$.

I've tried to solve this problem, but my approach leads to a nonsensical answer. Here's my work:
Let $A = \frac{X}{Y}$. I found the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $A$ to be:
$$F_A(a) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2a} & \frac{1}{2} \leq a \leq 1 \\ 1 - \frac{a}{2} & 1 < a \leq 2\end{cases}$$
Then, I attempted to find the conditional expectation using:
$$\mathbb{E}[A \mid X \leq 2Y] = \left(\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{-1}{2a} da + \int_1^2 \frac{-a}{2} da\right)$$
However, this approach yields a nonsense answer. Can someone please help me identify the mistake and provide a correct solution?

\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\frac XY<a|X<2y\right)&=\frac{\Pr\left(\frac XY<a,X<2y\right)}{\Pr\left(X<2y\right)}\\
&=\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{ if } \quad a \geq 2\\
\frac43\left(1-\frac1{2a}\right) \quad \text{ if } \quad 1 \leq a < 2\\
\frac23a \quad \text{ if } \quad 0 \leq a < 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Hence $$E\left(\frac XY|X<2y\right) = \int_1^2\left(1-\frac43\left(1-\frac1{2a}\right)\right)da + \int_0^1\left(1-\frac23a\right)da=\frac{1}{3} (1+\ln4).$$
This is a bit unfortunate, as my answer differs from the previous one by Robert. I have to recheck the details, maybe OP would like to do :-)

+1 Not to worry, Robert's conditional pdf should have had value $\frac  43$ instead of $1$, and adding this to his calculations makes his answer match yours,

Thanks a lot for checking @DilipSarwate; I just went off checking :-)

Your CDF for $X/Y$ can't be right because it's $1$ at $a=1/2$ and $0$ at $a=2$.  A CDF should be increasing, not decreasing.  I think you've calculated $\mathbb P(A \ge a)$ rather than $\mathbb P(A \le a)$. But I wouldn't do the question this way.
[EDITED to correct for the area of the trapezoid]
Conditional on $X \le 2 Y$, $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the trapezoid with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1/2)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$, which has area $3/4$.
So
$$ \eqalign{\mathbb E[X/Y\mid X \le 2 Y] &= \frac{4}{3}\int_0^1 dx \; \int_{x/2}^1 dy \; \frac{x}{y}\cr
&= - \frac{4}{3} \int_0^1 dx \; x \ln(x/2)\cr &= \left. \frac{4}{3}\left( - \frac{ x^2 \ln(x/2)}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4} \right) \right|_{x=0}^{1}\cr &= \frac{2 \ln(2)}{3} + \frac{1}{3}} $$
noting that $\lim_{x \to 0+} x^2 \ln(x/2) = 0$.

Using the definition  $E[Z|A]:=E[\mathbf{1}_AZ]/P(A)$ I obtain as result $(1+2\ln(2))/3$.

@Snoop same as my value below.

@Robert the integral does not add to 1: $\int_0^1\int_{x/2}^1dxdy\neq1$.

The conditional pdf has value $\dfrac 43$ on the trapezoidal region and so the final answer should be $\dfrac 13(1+\ln 4)$, the  same as the one obtained by @Math-fun.

I agree, using $U=-\log X$ and $V=-\log Y$ and the fact that $H=-U+V$  is bilateral exponential. Therefore $E(e^H|H<\log 2)=\frac{1}{3}(1+2\log 2).$
